# Django query aggregation

Tags: django, aggregation

Imagine a number guessing game where one person thinks of a number and another person has to guess it. The game is over if the correct number was guessed.

The models might look like this

```
class SecretNumber(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()

class Guess(models.Model)
    secretnumber = models.Foreignkey(SecretNumber)
    guess = models.IntegerField()
```

After having played four times, the database might look like this:

```
id  number  
==========
1   10
2   54
3   68
4   25

id  secretnumber_id     guess
=============================
1   1                   50
2   1                   30
3   1                   10
4   2                   99
5   2                   60
6   2                   54
7   3                   1
8   3                   68
9   4                   73
10  4                   34
11  4                   86
12  4                   51
13  4                   25
```

As you can see, the guesser was very lucky: it took him 3, 3, 2 and 4 guesses. But that's just to keep this example short.
Now I need to come up with a query which will allow to display the following data:

```
Nb. guesses     Count   
=====================
2               1
3               2
4               1
```

A manual SQL statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT inner_count AS 'Nb. guesses', count(inner_count) AS 'Count' FROM (
  SELECT secretnumber_id, count(id) AS inner_count FROM guess GROUP BY secretnumber_id
) GROUP BY inner_count
```

I thought about annotating an annotation, but this seems not to be possible.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django (ie models instead of classes), you want to use the [QuerySet aggregate functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)

e.g.

```
from django.db.models import Count
guesses = Guess.objects.values('secretnumber').annotate(Count('secretnumber'))
```

This will give you a queryset with a list of objects, which have a secretnumber and a count value.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Django and it's models.

Do you agree that your query will annotate the number of guesses to each secret number? Like this:

`
[
{'secretnumber__count': 3, 'secretnumber': 1}, 
{'secretnumber__count': 3, 'secretnumber': 2}, 
{'secretnumber__count': 2, 'secretnumber': 3}, 
{'secretnumber__count': 4, 'secretnumber': 4}, 
]
`

I need to go one step further and aggregate this result so I know how many games were solved with 1 guess, 2 guesses, ..., n guesses.

Comment: ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question. I can't test, but can you just add a second aggregation to the end: guesses = Guess.objects.values('secretnumber').annotate(Count('secretnumber')).values('secretnumber__count').annotate(Count('secretnumber__count'))

Comment: The query throws an error... FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'count' into field.

Comment: guesses = Guess.objects.values('secretnumber').annotate(secretnumber_count=Count('secretnumber')).values('sec‌​retnumber_count').annotate(Count('secretnumber_count'))

Comment: FieldError: Cannot compute Count('secretnumber_count'): 'secretnumber_count' is an aggregate

Comment: in which case I think the only solution is to explicitly add SQL via the extra() function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra